# Do all salts of sodium form colorless solutions?

Tags: analytical-chemistry

I read all salts from sodium salts form colorless solutions unless the anion is colored. Can someone explain?

Comment: There is nothing to explain, really. White paint is white and remains white, unless mixed with some paint colored other than white. Same thing here.

Comment: Salts containing a counterion that is coloured will be coloured. the colour won't come from the sodium.

Comment: So, you ask what, really? Why they are colorless?

Comment: New contributors need to be treated a bit more gently. Their questions generally indicate an introduction to the topic with unconnected facts. If we demonstrate one connection, they are likely to be able to make more connections, on their own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various colors of chemical compounds because *color* is dependent on all of the interactions of all the components of the mixture, including the concentration. Some materials can appear to be one color in dilute solution, but a significantly different color in concentrated solution, because the level of absorption at a particular wavelength becomes so high that it dominates the color.

In the case of the sodium salts, it turns out that sodium ion does not have an electronic transition in the visible range, so it's *invisible*! However, all the other materials, ions, compounds, etc., may contribute their own absorptions to the mixture.